# Enable Authors in Multiple Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types

I have found the below code to enable viewing the author of a custom post type and it works perfectly for one custom post type. But I need it to work for 4 custom post types called: detox, recipes, movements, lifestyle.

```
function add_author_support_to_posts() {
   add_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', 'author' ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_support_to_posts' );
```

What is the correct syntax to include all 4 custom post types?

Comment: Could you not copy paste the line multiple times but put a different post type in each? You don't need to do it in the 1 function call

Answer (score 0):

I would build a loop to pass all my cpt's into like so

```
function add_cpt_author_support( ) {

    $post_types = array('detox', 'recipes', 'movements', 'lifestyle');

    foreach ($post_types as $type) {
        add_post_type_support($type, 'author');
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_cpt_author_support' );
```

One other thought though, why aren't you just declaring support for authors when you register your custom post types?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much. Not sure what you mean by "declaring support for authors". My theme offers custom post types so I have just set them up there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_author_support_to_posts() {
    $args = array(
       'public'   => true,
       '_builtin' => false
    );

    $output = 'names';

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output ); 

    foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
        add_post_type_support( $post_type, 'author' );
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_support_to_posts' );
```

Getting all custom post types as array with **get_post_types** function. Then running a foreach loop and adding the **author** support to custom post types